# Re-define property-function in obj

Tags: javascript

I'm facing such problem.
I have a object from an library that generally says:

```
obj.childObj.doStuff({
   ....
   aProperty: function(params....){
      var xxx = this.someObj,
      e = this.someOtherObj;

      obj.doSomeXtraStuff();
   }
   ....
});
```

I would like to override the `aProperty();` and then the global `obj` to make a call
on my version, is that possibe in that config, and also it would be nice doing it without modifying the definition of the original obj? However I'm open to any suggestions.
I was able to make `aProperty.prototype = function(p1,p2,...){.....};`
but there was no effect, although it was saved in proto property?

Comment: `aProperty` is a function property of an anonymous object supplied as an argument to the `doStuff` function.  Without more information, no one can tell you what `doStuff` does with the `aProperty` function: it may store it, it may call it immediately and discard it, or it may even ignore it.  If you explain what library you're using (or at least how/if `aProperty` is available after the call to `doStuff`), that may be more helpful.

Comment: I'm using  Smart Client: Calendar.js and I'm trying to override the isc.EventWindow.addProperties({renderEvent:function()});